# In python, for imports is there a simple way to use the more common pathing syntax provided by most OS tools, PYcharm, etc?

Tags: python

Hi there I'm a former C# dev here switching over to python for a new project that we hope to incorporate machine learning into, thus python since tensorflow is the gold standard and it was first released in python.

I was just starting out writing my first few files and it's really interesting that the pathing for directories in python uses all dots. I'm not very used to that syntax and I was quite surprised python chose to change this from the more conventional slashes.

So for example in Python I find myself writing:

```
from package1.subpackage2.subpackage3.subpackage4.module5 import function6
```

and for every import I have to replicate that syntax?

It seems strange given the industry in general always uses slashes to denote paths. This winds up with dozens and dozens of tools not quite giving me something I can quickly iterate on. The OS in windows gives slashes, the OS in mac has multiple ways to copy path and they both also give slashes even though mac comes with python installed by default! Even when calling through file paths from a webserver or API you use slashes like so:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

or

`F:\Google\Chrome\Application\38.0.2125.111\Locales`

What is really crazy is, given this python specific IDE called PYCharm which I am just now learning, even it's paths when you select files and choose to copy paths comes to the clipboard using slashes! What gives?! Certainly the people building python specific IDEs would realize that syntax is not valid for imports and set it up so developers could use something that matches the way we have to write them.

So I've dug in and searched through stackoverflow and the broader web in general looking for a solution, but I don't see anything simple out there. Even the python docs don't mention a more appropriate approach! I'm hoping I am just missing something. Is there a tool that gives me the paths correctly for python?  Or were the python devs able to see this being an issue and maybe they set up an escape character I can use to easily format the slash paths that are common from all the other tools into my imports?

Comment: file paths in python still uses slashes. It is just the imports that use dots. I have never seen an import with more than 1 dot though. Is this your code that you are trying to refer to?

Comment: Just an example but similar! Using the machine learning libs we have has proven to be a lot of find replacing on slashes to dots! Hopefully I can find a simple process trim it down to just one step.

Comment: The import syntax used a python object hierarchy of packages, modules and objects, not a path. It looks like a path because the upper parts of the object hierarchy are derived from packages which are technically folders.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nope, anytime you need to use a simple path to a file through other directories you'll use the dots in python it's pretty tedious at first but you'll get used to it.

Comment: "anytime you need to use a simple path to a file through other directories you'll use the dots in python"—this is entirely false. See [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path), [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#module-glob), and [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) from the standard library, for example.

Comment: Imports simply don't use filesystem paths.

Comment: @chris This question is about imports, it has imports in the title.

Comment: Then answer about imports. Don't say "anytime you need to use a simple path to a file". And, ideally, note that imports _aren't filesystem paths_, because that's the core misunderstanding at play here.

Comment: The answer is about imports because it's a direct response to the question sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you [edit] your answer and make appropriate changes I will happily retract my downvote and delete my comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using pycharm, then it's very easy to use tab-expansion to build your import paths, or pycharm's recommendation is to use the auto-import features. Those are the more appropriate approaches. Either of these should be a lot faster than copy-pasting a file path and then replacing slashes manually. And in fact you shouldn't be copy-pasting file paths and modifying them to become imports anyway.

More on pycharm's auto-imports:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html

The key here is that packages and directories are *not* always the same thing. For instance, using an `__init__.py` you can define additional variables at the package-level that do not exist anywhere else in the files/directories of your project, or you can move functions defined at the package level up to the module level via the same mechanism. And if you're using tensorflow in Python then there should be no need to convert from slashes to dots, as any example you'll find is going to use dots for its imports.

Remember, when you import, you are not truly dealing with paths. You are dealing with packages and modules that *may* resolve to a valid path, but may not. And since everything involving actual file paths uses slashes, of course copy-pasting a path isn't going to convert that path to dots.